# Haskell ReadWriteMode file handle

Tags: haskell, io

While reading *Learn You A Haskell*, I found that you can use *ReadWriteMode* as the third parameter to `openFile`.

But is this supposed to handle writing and reading to a file?
I did some tests:

```
import System.IO

main = do
    handle   <- openFile "myfile" ReadWriteMode
    contents <- hGetContents handle
    putStrLn contents
    hPutStr handle "Something"
    hClose handle
```

However, this returned an error:

```
*** Exception: myfile: hPutStr: illegal operation (handle is closed)
```

So, what is the point of the *ReadWriteMode*? I am looking for any real world cases where this would be used.

Comment: [`hGetContents`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetContents) closes the handle. Try something like [`hGetLine`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.0.0/docs/System-IO.html#v:hGetLine).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something that seems to work.

```
import System.IO
import qualified System.IO.Strict as SIO
import GHC.IO.Handle

slurp h = do
  h' <- hDuplicate h
  hSeek h' AbsoluteSeek 0
  SIO.hGetContents h'

main = do
    handle   <- openFile "myfile" ReadWriteMode
    contents <- slurp handle
    putStrLn contents
    offset <- hTell handle
    putStrLn $ "handle position: " ++ show offset
    hPutStrLn handle "Something new"
    hClose handle
```

`System.IO.Strict` is from the [`strict` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/strict-0.3.2/docs/System-IO-Strict.html)

Edit: You might not even need to use `SIO.hGetContents` - just plain `hGetContents` also seems to work.